# changing the bgr color values of a picture on opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, bgr

My function below should change the color values of the original picture and then once the process is done it should create another picture with the changed colors.

```
void change(const cv::Mat &first_image, cv::Mat &new_image, const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &colors)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < first_image.cols; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < first_image.rows; j++) {

 int blue = first_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
 new_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2]= colors [2][blue];

 int green = first_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1];

 new_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1]= colors [1][green];

 int red = first_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2];

 new_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0]= colors [0][red];
}
}
}
```

when I use the command make and run the whole code I get a segmentation fault.
I use this command to run the code

```
../../build/mv/task/mvtask1d pic.json
```

Could someone tell me what I could be doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [`cv::Mat::at`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ac40425b84f60b39fd35e03814122661f) coordinate order is `(row, column)`. You've got it backwards.

Comment: @breaker thanks a lot :))